# request.redirect() for long URLs in struts2&IE

Tags: java, struts2, forward

I am using struts2. 
I have to redirect my system to a URL which is longer than 3000 characters. The url length causes the system to work incorrectly in IE because of the url limitation in get methods.
I have tried to use request dispatcher but i think i have a problem with action namespaces.

I need to forward from action 1 to action 2.

ACTION 1
Action Name : basket.action
Namespace : "/mike/jordan"

ACTION 2
Action Name : soccer.action (With a lot of parameters)
Namespace : "/david/beckham"

What i have so far is

```
RequestDispatcher reqDispatcher = getRequest().getRequestDispatcher("/david/beckham/soccer.action");
reqDispatcher.forward(getRequest(), getResponse());
```

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: why do you want to define it in action?

Comment: Yes, actually the second action and its parameters are dynamically created in the first action. Therefore I cannot use xml.

Comment: You can pass dynamic actionName in the result type. Or better to write a custom interceptor.

Comment: Look at the Store interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

[Struts2 redirect to another action](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

```
  <action name="login" class="...">
        <!-- Redirect to another namespace -->
        <result type="redirectAction">
        <param name="actionName">dashboard</param>
        <param name="namespace">/secure</param>
        <param name="param1">${param1}</param>
        <param name="param2">${param2}</param>
        </result>
  </action>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need to do it programatically. Not by using xml

Comment: Updated my answer to set dynamic parameters.